# Convert MatOfPoint2f to MatOfPoint

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm working in an opencv project for android. I need to convert a variable from `MatOfPoint2f` to `MatOfPoint`. As follows is the relevant part of my code: `approx` is of type `MatOfPoint2f` and I need to convert it because `drawContours` use type `ArrayList<MatOfPoint>`.

```
Imgproc.approxPolyDP(newMtx, approx, 0.02*peri, true);
approxMatOfPoint = (MatOfPoint) approx; // to convert
ArrayList<MatOfPoint> p = new ArrayList<>();
p.add(approxMatOfPoint);
Imgproc.drawContours(img, p, 0, new Scalar(0,255,0), 2);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved doing the following:

```
MatOfPoint approxf1 = new MatOfPoint();
...

Imgproc.approxPolyDP(newMtx, approx, 0.02*peri, true);
approx.convertTo(approxf1, CvType.CV_32S);
List<MatOfPoint> contourTemp = new ArrayList<>();
contourTemp.add(approxf1);
Imgproc.drawContours(img, contourTemp, 0, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
```

Cheers.